# integer expression expected error when trying to run a command on each line

Tags: bash, script

I am trying to essentially run a command on each line of a file. Below is what I have so far. I want to be able to take each line, take the last column from it, run a command on the integer and if it doesn't equal zero, echo the full line. I seem to be running into errors and can't seem to figure out where.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=\n
file=`cat /proc/user_beancounters`

for line in "$file"
do
    last_col=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $(NF)}'`

    if [ $last_col -ne 0 ]; then
            echo $last_col
    fi

done
```

Contents of /proc/user_beancounters:

```
Version: 2.5
       uid  resource                     held              maxheld              barrier                limit              failcnt
34579:  kmemsize                 28694400             33435648             67108864             67108864                    0
        lockedpages                     0                    0                   64                   64                    0
        privvmpages                473539               581717               786432               786432                  176
        shmpages                    26821                26821                43008                43008                    0
        dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
        numproc                       113                  159                  500                  500                    0
        physpages                  199504               208572               524288               524288                    0
        vmguarpages                     0                    0                98304                98304                    0
        oomguarpages               188782               191010                 6144                 6144                    0
        numtcpsock                     35                   37                  160                  160                    0
        numflock                        8                   11                  100                  100                    0
        numpty                          1                    1                  200                  200                    0
        numsiginfo                      0                   36                  500                  500                    0
        tcpsndbuf                  616080               650960              8388608              8388608                    0
        tcprcvbuf                  577800               621600              8388608              8388608                    0
        othersockbuf               108664               135616              8388608              8388608                    0
        dgramrcvbuf                     0                16184              8388608              8388608                    0
        numothersock                  116                  128                  500                  500                    0
        dcachesize                8375457              8388258              8388608              8388608                    0
        numfile                      2627                 2915                 8192                 8192                    0
        dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
        dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
        dummy                           0                    0  9223372036854775807  9223372036854775807                    0
        numiptent                     168                  168              9999999              9999999                    0
```

In the above example, I want the script to essentially pick out that "privvmpages" has failed more than once, and therefore echo the line:

```
privvmpages                473539               581717               786432               786432                  176
```

Or if possible, just the name "privvmpages" and the number "176"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

#### Using `bash`

The following works:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    last_col=`echo "$line" | awk '{print $(NF)}'`
    if [[ $last_col =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ && "$last_col" -ne 0 ]]; then
            echo $line
    fi    
done </proc/user_beancounters
```

Notes:

- The command `IFS=\n` sets `IFS` to the letter `n`.  This is not what you want.  If you really want `IFS` to be a newline, use instead `IFS=$'\n'`.
- `$last_col =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$`

  This test assures that `last_col` is an integer.  This has the effect of skipping over the header lines.

#### Using `awk`

Looping over the lines of a file is something that `awk` does naturally.  The above code can be replaced by:

```
 awk 'NR > 2 && $NF != 0' /proc/user_beancounters
```

Notes:

- `NR>2`

  The first two lines of the file are headers.  This skips over them.
- `$NF != 0`

  This selects lines whose last field is non-zero.
- with no explicit command associated with the above two conditions, `awk` will print the whole line.

Alternatively, if you want to print just the first and last column, use:

```
awk 'NR>2 && $NF != 0 {print $1,$NF}' /proc/user_beancounters
```

Comment: Since he wants the whole line: `awk 'NF>2 && $NF' file`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks! I was following the sample code (`echo $last_col`), but you are right: the text specifies the full line.  Answer updated.